# How to pass query string parameters with bs-fetch?

Tags: fetch-api, reason, bucklescript

What is the proper way to pass query string parameters to [`bs-fetch`](https://github.com/reasonml-community/bs-fetch)?

Currently, I have:

```rust
Fetch.fetch("https://example.com/api?param1=value1&param2=value2")
```

Obviously, this is not sustainable for larger parameter lists.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[re:fetch](https://github.com/glennsl/refetch) supports query params by way of either

```rust
request("https://example.com/api",
  ~queryParams=[
    ("param1", "value1"),
    ("param2", "value2")
  ])
|> fetch;
```

or

```rust
request("https://example.com/api")
|> Request.param("param1", "value1")
|> Request.param("param2", "value2")
|> fetch;
```

Beware that the library is experimental though. Alternatively, you could just swipe [the query builder code](https://github.com/glennsl/refetch/blob/master/src/Refetch__Request.re#L98-L112), which has been battle-tested at least a little bit (there's a subtle bug in @monssef's implementation when there's an empty list, and it also doesn't do proper encoding):

```rust
[@bs.val] external encodeURIComponent : string => string = "";

let _buildUrl = (url, params) => {
  let encodeParam = ((key, value)) =>
    encodeURIComponent(key) ++ "=" ++ encodeURIComponent(value);

  let params =
      params |> List.map(encodeParam)
             |> String.joinWith("&");

  switch params {
  | "" => url
  | _ => {j|$url?$params|j}
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

i don't think there's  something builtin for that.
just make your own query builder function, something like this

```
let payload = Js.Dict.empty();

Js.Dict.set(payload, "email", Js.Json.string("email@email.co"));

Js.Dict.set(payload, "password", Js.Json.string("secret"));

let query =
  Js.Dict.keys(payload)
  |> Array.fold_left(
       (query, key) =>
         switch (Js.Dict.get(payload, key)) {
         | Some(value) =>
           query ++ key ++ "=" ++ Js.Json.stringify(value) ++ "&"
         | _ => query
         },
       "?"
     );
```

here's a [link](https://reasonml.github.io/try.html?rrjsx=true&reason=FAGwpgLgBADghgTxAezgEygXigKQM4B0AIgJYDGEBYAtjBAgBQCUA3MMPseZXpA-ElRoANFABENOCRBjRnfMgB2BPBABOJRQHMGE6lJAABSdIJlkYpq3adSFFXwEp0osfDx4A7sjVpZuQgVlVQ1tXV4yNUhLa1BIKABHAFcwNQQsYCgArnsAazAEPH5EZzQmTKgAHwA%20KABBNTVEAgAzZBA0AH1wFogGCqzBhmTUhAAuKBDNLVF8hCYsaoHBwa8SCDIACygGW24CLUcSoVmCqygAb2WVqqgAZWRqMAYANzgQFIXMJZvfkbSoABqQFQOZAkFiTBicHZIIqdTTEgtRhvD5gBbA8QAMjE1xWlSgnUWiRSaTxgwAvsJyWIAPy4m7WTgoHT-eZsG5AA) to the playground.